# Partial fraction integration problem in calculus

Tags: calculus

$$ \int \frac{x^2-3x+7}{(x^2-4x+6)^2} dx =  \int
 \frac{1}{x^2-4x+6} +  \frac{x+1}{(x^2-4x+6)^2} dx
$$ $$=\int \frac{1}{(x-2)^2 +2} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x-4}{(x^2-4x+6)^2} +
\frac{3}{(x^2-4x+6)^2} dx $$

Here how can we calculate last term ?

[Supplement] --------

In followging article we can find a solving way :

[Partial fraction integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/partial-fraction-integration/17014#17014)

Comment: Continue expanding, note that $x^2-4x+6 = (x-2-i\sqrt{2})(x-2+i\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I cannot use it to this case. I know that expansion relating complex number is useful about this problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518779/closed-form-for-int-frac1x7-1-dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't been doing calculus with complex numbers, you want to "complete the square" in the denominator of the last term:

$$\frac{dx}{(x^2 -4x + 4 + 2)^2} \ = \ \frac{dx}{([x- 2]^2 + 2)^2} $$

and transform to a variable $ \ u \ = \ x - 2 \ $ , with $ \ du \ = \ dx \ \ :  \ \rightarrow \ \frac{du}{(u^2 + 2)^2} \ $ .  You then have something you can finish using a tangent substitution, $ \ u \ = \ \sqrt{2} \ \cdot \ \tan \theta \ : $

$$\rightarrow  \frac{\sqrt{2} \ \cdot \ \sec^2 \theta \ \ d\theta}{[ \ (\sqrt{2} \ \cdot \ \sec \theta)^2 \ ]^2 } \ \ .  $$

[*Note*:  this will reduce nicely to just having to integrate a constant times $ \ \cos^2 \theta \ $ , which after using the appropriate trig identity, will produce two terms in your complete anti-derivative.]